# Conditional sidebar google site

Tags: google-apps-script, navigation, google-sites

I was wondering if it is possible to show/hide links on the sidebar navigation of a Google Site based on what the email / permissions the end user has. Has anyone ever done anything like this? I don't see any options under "edit site layout", perhaps it can be done with Google Apps Script? If anyone has any resources / links to similar problems and solutions, that would be appreciated. I can't seem to find anything on the subject myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users will only see pages they have access to, so you can set individual page permissions and this will hide the page from some users.  I use Google Groups to define the permissions and add users to the appropriate groups.  If a user is in a group which has permissions to view, they have permissions to view. If they are in a group which has edit permissions, they have edit permissions.  They will get the highest permissions associated with all the groups they are a member for which is applied to that page.

Comment: I can't test it now, but I'm assuming the page link in the navigation would still be available and if you click the navigation link, A page with a permission request comes up. Is that correct?

Comment: The end user does not see the page's menu item.